# What is the efficiency of UV lamp in ozone generation (Ozone g vs. energy consumed )

Tags: ozone

re.:

What is the efficiency of UV lamp in ozone generation (Ozone g vs. energy consumed )

I read a lot of papers from the Internet on using UV lamp for generating ozone but none discussed the efficiency of such process.

How much energy (kWh) gets consumed by UV lamp to generate 1g of ozone ?

I read  Ozone Formation from UV Light
https://www.oxidationtech.com/ozone/ozone-production.html#answer2

and related web links
and all I get as pros and cons is:

"
Ozone production from UV light for commercial applications
Advantages of UV Ozone Generator

```
Simple Construction – only a UV lamp with ballast and a fan

Low cost – due to simple construction

Lower nitric oxide production
```

Disadvantages of UV Ozone Generator

```
Low ozone output – g/hr

Low ozone concentration – less than 1% by weight

Bulbs and ballasts will need to be replaced
```

"

Let me know your opinion

Comment: "How much energy (kWh) gets consumed by UV lamp to generate 1g/h of ozone ?" I think you can spot the problem with this question yourself. Do you?

Comment: I have asked alike question in Physics and was asked it to ask in Chemistry to get the correct answer

Comment: Either g per kWh, either g/h  per kW. Not g/h per kWh.

Comment: OK, two problems. ;-) The other is that UV light sources have their own efficency. Electricity -> UV photons (of what wavelength?) -> ozone

Comment: I read about UV light source efficiency from one boomarked site  but just visit UV Light Ozone Generators https://www.boie.us/uv-ultraviolet.php claiming ozone output: 10g/h and still no data on power consumed in the specification

"Lamps:
  Long-life VH** 9,000-hour high-output ozone lamps
not rated

"Electrical Rating:
  120V~60Hz 2.6 Amps

So in theory, power consumed is less than 120V x 2.6 Amps = 312W.

Hard to believe, low efficiency UV lamps can generate 10g/h ozone comsuming less than 1,000W x hr

Comment: great image of the opened box 
BoiE UltraViolet 10K Shock Model
https://www.boie.us/images/image-slider-uvozone.jpg

not sure 10K stays for what

" 10,000 mg/hr

Eureka!!!
10K stays for 10,000 mg/hr

to be verified

Comment: and one more 12V model of 12-volt corona discharge ozone generator
https://www.boie.us/dc-sportsman-pro.php

since ozone output is selectable, matching electrical rating, so
"Electrical Rating:
  12V DC 1.55A (Low) 4.45A (High)
matches
selectable ozone output (1,000 or 4,500 mg/hr) 

so 1,000 mg/hr consumes 18.6W x h
4,500 mg/hr .. 53.4W x h

4.5 x  18.6W = 83.7W

so a single generator consumes less energy than 4.5 stacked in parallel, generating the same amount of ozone.

Comment: ok, ..20W rated power, 12-volt corona discharge ozone
generates 1,000 mg/hr

vs. 

 312W UV light ozone generator generates 10g/hr,
so 30W UV ... generates 1g/hr

20W (corona) matches 30W (UV) rated 1g/h

since corona generator is much more complicated HV
I am going to build UV ozone generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about UV light source efficiency from one boomarked site but just visit UV Light Ozone Generators boie.us/uv-ultraviolet.php claiming ozone output: 10g/h and still no data on power consumed in the specification "Lamps: Long-life VH** 9,000-hour high-output ozone lamps not rated "Electrical Rating: 120V~60Hz 2.6 Amps So in theory, power consumed is less than 120V x 2.6 Amps = 312W. Hard to believe, low efficiency UV lamps can generate 10g/h ozone comsuming less than 1,000W x hr – a a Apr 28 at 20:11

great image of the opened box BoiE UltraViolet 10K Shock Model boie.us/images/image-slider-uvozone.jpg not sure 10K stays for what " 10,000 mg/hr Eureka!!! 10K stays for 10,000 mg/hr to be verified – a a Apr 28 at 23:07

and one more 12V model of 12-volt corona discharge ozone generator boie.us/dc-sportsman-pro.php since ozone output is selectable, matching electrical rating, so "Electrical Rating: 12V DC 1.55A (Low) 4.45A (High) matches selectable ozone output (1,000 or 4,500 mg/hr) so 1,000 mg/hr consumes 18.6W x h 4,500 mg/hr .. 53.4W x h 4.5 x 18.6W = 83.7W so a single generator consumes less energy than 4.5 stacked in parallel, generating the same amount of ozone. – a a Apr 28 at 23:17

ok, ..20W rated power, 12-volt corona discharge ozone generates 1,000 mg/hr vs. 312W UV light ozone generator generates 10g/hr, so 30W UV ... generates 1g/hr 20W (corona) matches 30W (UV) rated 1g/h since corona generator is much more complicated HV I am going to build UV ozone generator – a a Apr 28 at 23:24